# Qt Digia vs. Qt project

Tags: qt, qt5

Qt Digia provides cross platform development targeting Mac, PC, Linux and on mobile iOS, Android, Windows mobile.

The Qt project also offers iOS, Android and PC, Mac, Linux builds. What is additionally there on the commercial version (i.e. Qt Digia)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core is the same which means the essential modules and some shared extension modules, aka. add-ons. There are a couple of things differing, however, e.g.:

- [Boot2Qt](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/07/04/making-an-android-device-boot-to-qt/)
- [Android injection](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/07/03/introducing-android-injection-with-qt-enterprise-embedded-5-3-1/)
- [Qt Virtual Keyboard](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/07/03/qt-virtual-keyboard-1-1/)
- [Qt Quick Compiler](http://doc.qt.digia.com/QtQuickCompiler/)
- [Charts](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Enterprise/Charts/)
- [Qt Purchasing](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Enterprise/Qt-Purchasing/)

... and so on, basically anything that Digia is working on [under the Enterprise umbrella](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Enterprise/). You can follow [their blog](http://blog.qt.digia.com/) for further details.

[Here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/05/22/qt-enterprise-embedded-updated-to-qt-5-3/) you can also find the updates for 5.3.

On the new [qt.io download page](http://www.qt.io/download/) you can find a detailed table with a comparison about the available options.

Comment: I have a doubt here does it mean that there is no way to generate native code for mobile platforms using Qt Project?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. You can certainly write native code yourself or write a compiler, but the QML to C++ code compilation is enterprise material if that is what you mean. I do not think it is a big concern, however.

Comment: I mean isn't there a way to generate native code for android or iOS by using Qt project SDK (which is offered under GPL) ?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what native code means. I have the impression that you mean object code. That is a different thing, and that is possible for sure, even with the GPL version, although you cannot use that without opening up your code, but that is a different topic.